# Easy Ruby data table/search question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
A    B
A    C
B    A
C    A
C    B
```

I want to delete the lines that the connection of two values are already in represented (so A----B is the equivalent connection as B----A). Basically I want my table to look like this.

```
A    B
A    C
B    C
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

-Bobby

**EDIT:**

Here is my current code:

```
require 'rubygems'


f = File.new("uniquename.txt","w")
i = IO.readlines('bioportnetwork.txt').collect{|l| l.split.sort}.uniq
i.each do |z|
f.write(z + "\n")
end
```

I tried this code, but I think the IO.readlines did not read my columns correctly. Here is one part of my table.

```
9722,9754   8755
8755         9722,9754
9722,9754   7970,7971
7970,7971    9722,9754
```

How can I get it read correctly, then saved out correctly as a TSV file?

-Bobby

Comment: Table as in "database table" or...?

Comment: I have a tab separated text file.

Comment: When you say "part of my table", is that what your input file looks like?  That's completely different than your original example.  If that's not from your input file, please provide a sample from your actual input file.

Comment: Here is a sample of my data:

http://rapidshare.com/files/412612671/Sample_Data.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'table' you mean an array-of-arrays similar to this:

```
x = [['A', 'B'],
     ['A', 'C'],
     ['B', 'A'],
     ['C', 'A'],
     ['C', 'B']]
```

If so, you can de-duplicate the list with `x.collect{|a| a.sort}.uniq`.

**Update:**
To read the data out of the file and into the array, use something like:

```
lines = IO.readlines('filename.txt')
x = []
lines.each {|l| x << l.split}
```

**Update 2:**
Or, you can one-line the whole thing:

```
IO.readlines('test.txt').collect{|l| l.split.sort}.uniq
```

**Update 3:**
When writing out to the file, don't use `IO.write`.  It converts the array to a string automatically, which might be where you are running into your problem.  Instead, use `IO.puts`:

```
f.puts x[0].to_s << "\t" << x[1].to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

So, let's say you have loaded your TSV file into an array of pairs:

```
arr = [["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "A"], ["C", "A"], ["C", "B"]]
Hash[arr.map{|pair| [pair.sort, pair]}].values
#=> [["B", "A"], ["C", "A"], ["C", "B"]]
```

This is OK if the order of pairs in original array is not important.

And if neither order of elements in pairs is important:

```
arr.map(&:sort).uniq
#=> [["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "C"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Set equivalency is defined in ruby, and Sets use equivalency only to check new members, so you can use a nested set structure to solve this quickly and easily.

```
set_of_all_sets = Set.new
file.each_line do |line|
  line =~ /(\S)\s(\S)/
  set_of_all_sets << Set.new([$1, $2])
end
array_of_all_sets.map{|set| set.to_a}
```